# Как расположить псевдо элемент под его родителем?

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том что я пытаюсь с позиционировать псевдо элемент(серый квадрат) под его родителя, но не выходит он наслаивается на родителя. Пробовал решить проблему с помощью z-index, не помогло.

```css
.shop__wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
      -ms-flex-align: end;
          align-items: flex-end;
  background: blueviolet;
  max-width: 312px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 46px;
}

.shop__logo {
  font-family: "Poppins Bold", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.shop__text {
  font-family: "Moms", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.shop__sizes {
  max-width: 195px;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
      -ms-flex-pack: start;
          justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.shop__subtitle {
  font-family: "Poppins Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-right: 11px;
}

.shop__blocks {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.shop__label {
  font-family: "Poppins Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
}

.shop__label {
  position: relative;
}

.shop__input {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.shop__span-size {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.shop__span-size::before,
.shop__span-color::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: #373737;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -3px;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0);
          transform: scale(0);
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out  0.6s;
  transition: all ease-in-out  0.6s;
  z-index: 1;
}

.shop__span-size-s::before {
  left: -7px;
}

.shop__span-size-m::before {
  left: -6px;
}

.shop__span-size-l::before {
  left: -8px;
}

.shop__span-size-xl::before {
  left: -4px;
}

.shop__input:checked + .shop__span-size::before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}

.shop__colors {
  max-width: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.shop__span-color {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.shop__span-color-black {
  background: #000000;
}

.shop__span-color-white {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.shop__input:checked + .shop__span-color::before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}

.shop__span-color::before {
  top: -3px;
  left: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shop__wrapper">
                                        <div class="shop__sizes">
                                            <div class="shop__subtitle">Size:</div>
                                            <div class="shop__blocks">
                                                <div class="shop__block">
                                                    <label class="shop__label">
                                                        <input class="shop__input"  type="radio" value="1" name="Size-2">
                                                        <span class="shop__span-size shop__span-size-s">S</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="shop__block">
                                                    <label class="shop__label">
                                                        <input class="shop__input" type="radio" value="2" name="Size-2">
                                                        <span class="shop__span-size shop__span-size-m">M</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="shop__block">
                                                    <label class="shop__label">
                                                        <input class="shop__input" type="radio" value="3" name="Size-2">
                                                        <span class="shop__span-size shop__span-size-l">L</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="shop__block">
                                                    <label class="shop__label">
                                                        <input class="shop__input" type="radio" value="4" name="Size-2">
                                                        <span class="shop__span-size shop__span-size-xl">XL</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="shop__colors">
                                            <div class="shop__block-color">
                                                <label class="shop__label">
                                                    <input class="shop__input" name="Color-2" type="radio" value="1">
                                                    <span class="shop__span-color shop__span-color-black"></span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="shop__block-color">
                                                <label class="shop__label">
                                                    <input class="shop__input" name="Color-2" type="radio" value="2">
                                                    <span class="shop__span-color shop__span-color-white"></span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Вот как должно быть

[image: пример]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```css
.shop__wrapper {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: end;
      -ms-flex-align: end;
          align-items: flex-end;
  background: blueviolet;
  max-width: 312px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto 46px;
}

.shop__logo {
  font-family: "Poppins Bold", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.shop__text {
  font-family: "Moms", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.shop__sizes {
  max-width: 195px;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
      -ms-flex-pack: start;
          justify-content: flex-start;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.shop__subtitle {
  font-family: "Poppins Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin-right: 11px;
}

.shop__blocks {
  max-width: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
      justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

.shop__label {
  font-family: "Poppins Regular", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 120%;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
}

.shop__label {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.shop__input {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 0;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.shop__span-size {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.shop__span-size::before,
.shop__span-color::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  background: red;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: -1;
}

.shop__span-size-s::before {
  left: -7px;
}

.shop__span-size-m::before {
  left: -6px;
}

.shop__span-size-l::before {
  left: -8px;
}

.shop__span-size-xl::before {
  left: -4px;
}

.shop__input:checked + .shop__span-size::before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}

.shop__colors {
  max-width: 75px;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

.shop__span-color {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
  transition: all ease-in-out 0.6s;
}

.shop__span-color-black {
  background: #000000;
}

.shop__span-color-white {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.shop__input:checked + .shop__span-color::before {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
          transform: scale(1);
}

.shop__span-color::before {
}
```

```html
<div class="shop__wrapper">
                                        <div class="shop__sizes">
                                            <div class="shop__subtitle">Size:</div>
                                            <div class="shop__blocks">
                                                <div class="shop__block">
                                                    <label class="shop__label">
                                                        <input class="shop__input"  type="radio" value="1" name="Size-2">
                                                        <span class="shop__span-size shop__span-size-s">S</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="shop__block">
                                                    <label class="shop__label">
                                                        <input class="shop__input" type="radio" value="2" name="Size-2">
                                                        <span class="shop__span-size shop__span-size-m">M</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="shop__block">
                                                    <label class="shop__label">
                                                        <input class="shop__input" type="radio" value="3" name="Size-2">
                                                        <span class="shop__span-size shop__span-size-l">L</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="shop__block">
                                                    <label class="shop__label">
                                                        <input class="shop__input" type="radio" value="4" name="Size-2">
                                                        <span class="shop__span-size shop__span-size-xl">XL</span>
                                                    </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="shop__colors">
                                            <div class="shop__block-color">
                                                <label class="shop__label">
                                                    <input class="shop__input" name="Color-2" type="radio" value="1">
                                                    <span class="shop__span-color shop__span-color-black"></span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="shop__block-color">
                                                <label class="shop__label">
                                                    <input class="shop__input" name="Color-2" type="radio" value="2">
                                                    <span class="shop__span-color shop__span-color-white"></span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```